# What do we mean by 'defining a function'?

Tags: education, elementary-functions

First I will start by quote from Wikipedia about function's defining methods :

> There are many other ways of defining functions. Examples include
>   piecewise definitions, induction or recursion, algebraic or analytic
>   closure, limits, analytic continuation, infinite series, and as
>   solutions to integral and differential equations. The lambda calculus
>   provides a powerful and flexible syntax for defining and combining
>   functions of several variables. In advanced mathematics, some
>   functions exist because of an axiom, such as the Axiom of Choice.

I'm begin studying math at my own, I have started with Functions but I got confused regarding the term 'define a function' Is it really all those things 'induction,recursion,algebraic and analytic closure,limits, ... ' only for defining the Function ? then what do we mean by 'define the function' ? and why it's important so much that you can do it In many and diverse Ways ?

Note : I'm absolute beginner
The Math studying in the school ' also in the first years of university study' does not provide you The very basic Concepts like 'What really is function' or 'Derivation',Rather than you directly find yourself learning How to solve Function ! or How to do the 'Derivation' For me I do not like this approach, I love math but I can not continue in something I don't understand properly 
 Please Consider this Note while you help me in my issue

Comment: Let me paraphrase: There are many ways to build a home. It can be built of stone, bricks, wood, metal, glass, and other materials in various combinations; it may be constructed as an apartment or flat within a much larger building, built on the ground but attached to other homes on one or more sides, or completely separate. It may have one or more rooms on one or more separate levels; it may be flat on top, sloped on top, or have multiple flat and/or sloped areas on top; it may even be partly underground. What is so important about "home" that we can build one in so many diverse ways?

Comment: @DavidK this example is Great but I haven't understood yet why I Must define the Function ? what is the purpose of this step

Comment: You cannot have a home unless someone has built it, isn't that true?

Comment: Yes it is true,does that mean defining function is to 'Draw' this function 'edges' or 'define' the possible inputs and outputs of this function so that another value is considered as it did not met the function conditions 'crossed the boundaries or edges of this function' ?

Comment: I agree with Tryss about what "defining a function" is. My point is that you do not need to know everything about the building trades in order to understand what a home is for, or to be able to build a simple home. It is much like that when doing mathematics. If and when you need to build something more sophisticated, you may learn the necessary techniques then.

Comment: Oh ! You are right I'm sorry maybe I am too excited

Comment: That's quite all right; I will not complain when someone is excited by math. It's been a pleasure to participate in this discussion. May you have happy studies!

Comment: The pleasure was mine, you have given me a priceless information and great Way to tell me that I should calm down and go on step by step Thank you again !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, defining a function $f:E\to F$ is to give a subset $A$ of $E\times F$ that verifies certain properties. Or in other words, to give a set $A$ of couples $(x,y) \in E\times F$, such that for every $x\in E $ you have one and only one $y \in F$ such that $(x,y) \in A$, and we often note this $y$ as $f(x)$.

This is how to define a function by the "fundamental definition of a function", but you can define a function by **giving a set of properties that this function must verify**. However, the hard part when you do it this way is to show that it indeed defines a function, and that this function is unique.

How can I define something that is not a function? Take this:

> let $f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ the function that verify the following propriety:
>
> $f(n)$ is the number $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $t^2 = n$

This defines a relation (**not** a function), as the set of couples $(n,y)$ that verify this property ("$y^2=n$") doesn't follow the axioms of a function:

- there is no $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(-1) = y$
- there is more than one  $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(1) = y$

And the property that defines the function can be complex:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function that is derivable and verify $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ f'(x) = f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$

And this indeed defines a function (even if it's not trivial to show that it defines a function, rather than a relation)

In the end, the limit is this: you can define a function by giving it a property that characterizes it completely

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, Can you please tell me what the meaning of 'E×F'  does it mean 'E and F' ? and what do you mean by 'and that this function is unique' Why function should be unique ? and what does 'Uniqueness' mean in this context ? Finally can I summarize your answer as 'Defining function is to prove that one and only one element from the Set of Inputs associated with one element from the set of outputs' ??

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's a very important notation : $E\times F$ is the cartesian product of the set E and the set F, the elements of this set are the couples (x,y) , with x in E and y in F : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product . The function must be unique, because when you define an object, you want your definition to be **unambigous**. If I define the number 1, I want it to be a single object. Of course you can define a set or a familly of object, but then, you define a set.

Comment: Sorry I know the cartesian product but I didn't know that cartesian product denoted by × symbol,now does this mean the function is defined by Identify the possible values of the Functions inputs and outputs which fulfill the followed criteria/rule 'f:E→F ∀x ∈ E => f(x) ∈ F' and for each x there must be one and only one associated f(x)/y ?

Comment: Indeed, that's the "fundamental" definition of a function

Comment: Thank you sir, Now I feel like I'm Superman :) this simple concept takes this much to be understood ! then what will happens to me with more difficult concepts

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, a function is just a way of assigning a (unique) output to every input in some set. For example, for any set, it's possible to define the identity function, whose output is the same as its input. Equivalently, we could write $f_1(x) = x$. Or if we are interested in numbers, we could have the function which doubles its input: $f_2(x) = 2x$.

Now already I've defined functions (described how to get an output from any valid input) in two different ways: in words, and through a formula. There's also the factorial function, which is given by multiplying all integers up to the input:

$$
n! = 1 \times 2 \times \ldots \times n
$$

which can equivalently be defined "inductively" by

$$
0! = 1 \\
n! = n \times (n-1)!
$$

Normally, an author will choose to define a function in a way that makes its key properties easiest to prove; they might also use a definition that is most intuitive for some application, or do both and show that they are equivalent.

As a bit of personal advice, at this stage in your mathematical learning, don't worry too much about this in the abstract. It'll make sense as you encounter different functions in various contexts and you'll become used to all the ways that they can be defined.

And finally, to make what I said in the first paragraph more precise, and for the sake of completeness, normally a function $f$ with domain $A$ and range $B$ is defined as a subset of the Cartesian product $A \times B$ such that for every $a_0 \in A$, there is a unique pair $(a, b) \in f$ with $a_0 = a$, which we notate as $f(a_0) = b$.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to understand the above answer and I really appreciate the advice you have given me But I will be grateful if you expand your advice, I don't know why I can't ignore those concepts which I do not understand, I feel scattered whenever I face those concepts,What do you recommend ?